# Merge two dataframes of different dimension, without having NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, dataset, match

I am trying to merge two different dataframes on R. One dataframe is of about 5000 observations (dataframeA), while the other one is of 500 (dataframeB). The data is about ZIP codes. Using the package `zipcodeR` I created dataframeB from dataframeA. In fact, among all of the 5000 observations of dataframeA there were only 500 different ZIP codes. Now I want to extract the city from dataframeB and add it to every row of dataframeA with the corresponding ZIP code. How can I do it?

Here's a little example of what I'm doing:

```
# DataframeA
ID   ZIP
1    91107
2    90089
3    91107
4    91107
5    94720

# DataframeB
zipcode  city
90089    Los Angeles
91107    Pasadena
94720    Berkeley

# FINAL DATASET I WANT
ID   ZIP     city
1    91107   Pasadena
2    90089   Los Angeles
3    91107   Pasadena
4    91107   Pasadena
5    94720   Berkeley
```

Do you have any idea of how to do it?
I read something about if-else, but I had no good results.
Another option was:
`dataframeA$city <- dataframeA$city[match(dataframeA$ZIP, dataframeB$city)]`, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few solutions you can use. I recommend the second solution which uses `dplyr`, however the first solution also works fine.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:5,
  ZIP = c(91107,
          90089,
          91107,
          91107,
          94720)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  zipcode = c(90089,
              91107,
              94720),
  city = c("Los Angeles",
           "Pasadena",
           "Berkeley")
)

# Base R
merge(df1, df2, by.x = "ZIP", by.y = "zipcode")
#>     ZIP ID        city
#> 1 90089  2 Los Angeles
#> 2 91107  1    Pasadena
#> 3 91107  3    Pasadena
#> 4 91107  4    Pasadena
#> 5 94720  5    Berkeley

# dplyr/tidyverse
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("ZIP" = "zipcode"))
#>   ID   ZIP        city
#> 1  1 91107    Pasadena
#> 2  2 90089 Los Angeles
#> 3  3 91107    Pasadena
#> 4  4 91107    Pasadena
#> 5  5 94720    Berkeley
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I have another question: from 5000 in the bigger dataset, the observations become 5500. Do you know why?

Comment: This is likely because your second dataset has duplicate / non-unique values of `zipcode`. I recommend reading [this vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html) on mutating joins if you're unfamiliar with these concepts. In the meantime, please consider accepting my solution as it seems the original question has been answered!